# How to produce URL from router path and params in node.js

Tags: node.js, url, routes

Let's say I have a "router path" (not sure what the term is exactly) that is passed to express/restify to register a route (say, `'/category/:id'`) and a params object `{ id: 1234 }`. How I can combine them into URL `'/category/1234'`, is there an npm package that can do it?

Comment: What are you combining them for? Is it within the middleware? Are you using this middleware for various paths, or just category? Is the param always id? Are you just looking for the path that was actually called?

Comment: the purpose is quite complex to explain, but this is not within the middleware, and I'm not looking for the path that was actually called :) And of course 'category' and 'id' is just examples, I'm looking for a general solution :)

Comment: what I'm looking for is something similar to ES6's string interpolation for this path style, so that `somePackage('/category/:id', {id: id})` should give the same result as `\`/category/${id}\``. What I'm looking for is that `somePackage()`

Comment: I don't know of a package that exists, but I can write you a function when I'm done helping someone else :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the rout's path (string) and your params object, you can generate the path with this function :

```
function replace_tokens(string,data){
    var keys = Object.keys(data);
    for(var i in keys){
        string = string.replace(":" + keys[i],data[keys[i]]);
    }
    return string;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, a nice solution :)

Comment: You're very welcome.  Don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I also found out that [restify does have a utility](http://restify.com/#routing) (Hypermedia subsection) that does the job similar to this with `server.router.render(routeName, params, queryString)`. Maybe it would be useful in some cases.